# Stop refresh of LWC on mobile

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, mobile

Good day,

Is there a way to ensure that I can prevent my custom LWC, so it doesn't refresh when I pull down on the mobile screen?

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using **WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload**.

The onbeforeunload property of the WindowEventHandlers mixin is the EventHandler for processing beforeunload events. These events fire when a window is about to unload its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

Read more here :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: thanks @sanket, let me try that and see